# Binary tree node mirror - fill in the blanks

Tags: java, binary-tree

I'm currently studying for an exam and looking at the previous years exam question, it had this one about a binary tree where you have to fill in the blanks so that the function will the binary tree's node children.

I don't really know much about nodes, but logically I made a guess but I'm not sure if it's correct or not.

Here's the question:

```
public void mirror() {
     mirror(root);
}

private void mirror(Node node) {

    if (node != null) {

       // do the subtrees
       mirror(__________);
       mirror(__________);
       // swap the left/right pointers
       Node temp = __________;
       ______________________;
       ______________________;
     }
}
```

Here's my answer:

```
public void mirror() {
     mirror(root);
}

private void mirror(Node node) {

    if (node != null) {

       // do the subtrees
       mirror(node.left);
       mirror(node.right);
       // swap the left/right pointers
       Node temp = node.left;
       node.left = node.right;
       node.right = temp;
     }
}
```

If someone could please help me out and tell me if I'm on the right track, and if not, what it should look like please ! :)

Have a nice weekend!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best answered by testing the code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Good luck on the exam.

Comment: Sorry, this is not an answer...

Comment: Yes it is. 

He answered my question = It's an answer